# How to configure an jQuery event not to propagate before firing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I know there's a lot of similar questions on SO, but none of them addresses this situation.

Consider this code:

```js
//elements
var parent = $("#parent");
var button = $("button");
var version = $('#version');

version.text('jQuery ' + jQuery.fn.jquery);

//dispatcher
var eventDispatcher = {
  trigger: function(targetElement, eventName) {
    var ev = new jQuery.Event(eventName);
    ev.stopPropagation();
    jQuery(targetElement).trigger(ev);
  }
}

//events
version.bind('custom', function(){
  button.text('version custom');
});

parent.bind('custom', function(){
  button.text('parent custom');
});

button.bind("click", function(){
  eventDispatcher.trigger(version, 'custom');
});
```

```css
body { background: #333; padding: 20px; font-family: Helvetica; }

#parent { background: #0c0; padding: 20px; font-size: 25px; 
  text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; width: 300px; }

button { background: #fff; border: none; border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px; font-size: 15px; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <p id="version">jQuery Version</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

The dispatcher must fire only the child element's event.
I can't just put stopPropagation() on the child's event declaration, because it's the dispatcher that decides if the event is going to propagate or not.

Context

I'm upgrading an old project. In jQuery 1.5.1 the dispatcher worked, but on newer versions, it don't.

How to configure an jQuery event not to propagate beyond the target element, before firing the event.

Comment: stop propagation and event dispatching - two worst anti patterns. In newer versions all of the event stuff has been redone. You will have a headache going forward without refactoring. I if you are going to redo the you move to TypeScript (using it properly) and start using the newer ways of doing all this. If you not then dont upgrade, pollyfill what you are missing. Good luck soldier! (jq 1.5 -> 1.7 big changes then 1.7 -> 2 big changes then 3 drops all the crap)

Comment: I agree. On newer projects, we don't even use jQuery. But I have to keep this old project working. I was hopping to upgrade jQuery to, at least, version 1.12

Comment: Why do you need to upgrade? What functionality do you need?

Comment: There was a few bugs in the system that were fixed by upgrading jQuery. Also, some new plugins, that were added recently, require newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: Interesting. I know allot of things were fixed in 1.7.2 - You will have to look at using the events differently. Probably using the DOM Event handler instead of jQuery one